# SQL Server Merge statement in handling type 2 dimensions

Tags: sql-server

I have a merge statement in place to handle type 2 dimensions.

- The source table has a `source_eff_date` column .
- The target table has two columns (`source_eff_date` and `retired_date`).

Example

**source** table

```
c_id  f_name  l_name          source_eff_date 
1      FN1    LN1       04/15/2013
```

TARGET TABLE

```
c_i, f_name  l_name          source_eff_date retired_date
1      FN1    LN1       04/15/2013      12/12/2099
```

source table

```
c_id f_name l_name           source_eff_date 
1      FN1    LN2       05/15/2013
```

TARGET TABLE

```
c_id, f_name,l_name,source_eff_date retired_date
1      FN1    LN1       04/15/2013   05/14/2099
1      FN1    LN2       05/15/2013   12/12/2099
```

I am achieving the above requirement using a merge statement.

The question I have is, within the merge statement, I want to  write a record to the log table, if the source_eff_date for a record on the source table is older than the record in the target table.  consider the below scenario.

source table

```
c_id f_name l_name         source_eff_date 
1      FN1    LN2       02/15/2013
```

TARGET TABLE

```
c_id,     f_name,l_name,          source_eff_date retired_date
1           FN1    LN1      04/15/2013   05/14/2099
1           FN1    LN2                   05/15/2013   12/12/2099
```

I would like to reject this record from the merge statement(write to a log) and continue with merging other records. Hope I am clear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.